# How to prevent calling ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> after every api call in spring security with oauth2?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices

I have a requirement in my current project where I need to do some operation just after authentication user by calling `/oauth/token`. So I wrote a class like this

```
@Component
public class AuthSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

  @Value("${ationet.auth.url}")
  private String ationetUrl;

  private final TokenStore tokenStore;
  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
  private final AtionetService ationetService;

  public AuthSuccessListener(
      TokenStore tokenStore, RestTemplate restTemplate, AtionetService ationetService) {
    this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    this.ationetService = ationetService;
  }

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
    RedisService<String> redisService = new RedisService<>();
    String bespokeAccessToken = null;
    String ationetAccessToken = null;

    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    List<OAuth2AccessToken> tokens =
        (List<OAuth2AccessToken>)
            tokenStore.findTokensByClientIdAndUserName("unipet", userDetails.getUsername());
    bespokeAccessToken =
        tokens.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst()
            .map(OAuth2AccessToken::getValue)
            .orElse(null);

    try {
      String ationetAccesstoken =
          ationetService.getAccessToken("abc@gmail.com", "password");
      if (ationetAccesstoken != null) {
        redisService.setValue(bespokeAccessToken, ationetAccessToken);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem is this method is being called after every api call. As a result api response became slow and the same thing happening again and again after every api call. So my requirement is I want to do this operation once just after authenticating a user, not after every api call.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a judgment condition.

```
if (event.getSource().getClass().getName().equals("org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken"))
```